# Правильна ли пунктуация? Пытались или пыталась?

Tags: пунктуация, единственное-множественное-число

Построенная в 957 году, она представляла собой богатейший город и… бельмо в глазу древних завоевателей: вначале – монголы, затем – Тамерлан, а после – Оттоманская империя пытались покорить горожан.

Answer (score 2):

В целом всё верно, но тире здесь чисто интонационные, авторские. Если следовать правилам, их следует убрать:

*Построенная в 957 году, она представляла собой богатейший город и… бельмо в глазу древних завоевателей: вначале  монголы, затем  Тамерлан, а после  Оттоманская империя пытались покорить горожан.*

Культура речи публицистического или научного текста не рекомендует использовать "после" в качестве наречия (только как предлог — с родительным падежом: после чего-то), это разговорное употребление, лучше заменить на "потом".

Употребление множественного числа корректно, ведь здесь 3  деятеля, все они пытались покорить.